# Searching for a jQuery plugin: Does this exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I want to combine a content slider with a fancybox, lightbox type plugin. Does a plugin like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a lightbox plugin and simply put a content slider plugin inside of it.

Most lightbox plugins you should be able to define the specific html content of it. So then within this content you would place the content slider.

Although I haven't used a content slider, http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ is what I would recommend for lightboxes.

Comment: +1 Ben. I like Fancybox for lightbox, and check [this awesome screencast](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/) from Remy Sharp on creating a slider. You can build your slider inside a `<div/>` then add that div to your lightbox content.